# When i try to execute foreach statement i am getting -Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-controller

i am working on mvc project. In my controller i am calling my stored procedure from terms class and I am returning **Index** page if it returns true or return **terms** page if it returns false.

**Calling stored procedure in terms page :**

```
public class Accept
{

    public void Check()
    {

        using (var ctx = new termsEntities())
        {
            ctx.usp_ChkTerms(8, new ObjectParameter("Accepted", typeof(bool)));
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}
```

**Now i am calling this in my controller :**

```
public ActionResult App()
{

    // calling Stored procedure from Model to class            
    var accept = new Accept();
    accept.Check();

    // checking if accepted is true then return view else return another view
    AppEntities Accepted = new AppEntities();
    AppTerm user = new AppTerm();
    AppHist history = new AppHist();
    user = (from AppTerm app in Accepted.AppTerms
            where app.userID == 8
            select app).ToList().FirstOrDefault();


    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.Accepted)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {

            return View("terms");
        }
    }
```

**And this is the code i am using in my terms view :**

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "terms";
   }
  <html>

    <body>
       <ul>

          @foreach ( var item in Model)
           {
     <div class="Page"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Info", new { id = item.ID       })'">
     span class="Col1">
                            <br />
                            @item.ID
                        </span>
   <span class="Title">@item.Name</span>
    }
  </ul>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Here when condition is true it is displaying Index page but when condition falls and when it tries to display terms page i am getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** and error is pointing to foreach loop. so what mistake i am doing here? i need help..

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly, but you may try

```
<div class="Page"  onclick='location.href=&quot;@Url.Action("Info", new { id = item.ID       })&quot;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="Page"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Info", new { id = item.ID       })'">
```

Change this to:

```
 <div class="Page"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action('LinkText','Info', new { id = item.ID       })'">
```

Note the quote marks around `Info`

**edit:**
Added extra argument to link.

Comment: Hi if i change to single quote i am getting this error-- **Invalid arguments**

Comment: Hi its not working.again showing invalid arguments. are you sure that i am having problem here?